# DRF Custom Permission not blocking the view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So for my project I was trying to implement custom permissions for a view. I created the permission in `permissions.py`, which looks like this:

```
class TeamViewPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission for viewing team pages
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        team_id = self.kwargs.get('team_id')
        teamqs = MAIN_TEAMS.all()
        pk_list = []
        for item in MAIN_TEAMS:
            pk_list.append(str(item.pk))
        if team_id in pk_list:
            return True
        return False
```

Pretty simple, checks if the configuration team is matching the team page you're requesting and blocking the user out if that is not the case.

The `views.py`:

```
class PlayerList(ListView):

    model = player_model
    template_name = 'player_list.html'
    permission_classes = (TeamViewPermission, )

def get_team(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_team'):
        team_id = self.kwargs.get('team_id')
        self._team = team_model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('team_id'))
    return self._team

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['team'] = self.get_team()
    return context

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    return queryset.filter(team_id=self.kwargs.get('team_id'))
```

I know for a fact that the page returns True or False when it should, because I debugged it, although it's not blocking the page out? It returns False for the page, but I can still access the page like it returned True .. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add the code of your view?

Comment: Yeah, i have added it now. It's really not much there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing djangos class based views and the DRF views. 
`ListView` is a class based view from django and NOT from DRF. It therefore does not allow to set `permission_classes`.

Check [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) to see how to use DRF api views.

Comment: Ah I see .. What a mistake haha. I will pay more attention to that the next time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, accept and upvote, please.